# I'm using the media video module, how do I upload alternative webm and mp4 versions?

Tags: media

Server hosted video. Using the core video field. I'd like to put up a webm version, but also a mp4 version encoded for safari. Create a video block with 2 source items

```
<video>
   <source src="sourcea.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="sourceb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built in and simple solution

1. Video media type display

Admin > structure > media > video > display

Under display set multiple videos to a single html tag

[image]

2. Set the video field to allow 2 videos to be uploaded

Admin > structure > media > video > field settings

[image]

3. Upload 2 videos

[image]

I've got 2 versions in the video tag

```
<video controls="controls" width="640" height="480">
  <source src="/files/2021-04/Destination-Pagoda-Final-Version-web.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/files/2021-05/Pagoda-Final-Version-web.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```